# Beginning consonants sounds. Are those mixed sounds?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm watching [this video](https://youtu.be/0ZhOeA0RD9o?t=15m20s) where beginning consonants are explained. It seems to me that most of the sounds are a mixed version of the ones that we usually have in english. For example ㄱ has phonetic value [k/g] which seems to me is neither a [k] or a [g] but a mixed version, because I have the feeling I can hear both sounds. Am I right?

(Side question : what's the meaning of "phonetic value"?)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

(1) ㄱ [k/g] does not mean that ㄱ sounds k or g. It means that ㄱ
**sounds like** k or g. Therefore, you are right.

(2) Phonetic value of ㄱ means a sound. When we pronounce 가게
(shop), there is a sound for ㄱ so that it has a phonetic value.

Hence its phonetic value is almost same to k, g or their mixing.

Comment: But is there any reference for korean sounds? Like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azky_OVMplQ?